# jQGrid: how i can map different select option onto different rows and same column

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Hi have a table to show from xmlString using jqgrid.
the table has some rows, and there is a column which i want to get dynamically.
the select box can contain values based on db output, say values: textbox, textarea, radiobox.. it can have all or few as per enrty in db.

now i want to load the drop down with these values on inline editing. i am able to do that.
Problem arises when editoption values does not match one of the values selected.

For example i selected radiobutton from first dropdown, on next row i click for inline editing and dropdown dont have radiobutton  option, in this case the data in prev row for dropdown(radiobutton) gets blank which i selected .

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

got a solution:

onSelectRow: function(id){
                         if(id && id!==lastsel2){
                          jQuery("#list").saveRow(lastsel2, false, 'clientArray');
                          jQuery("#list").setColProp("Display_Type", { editoptions: { value: GetDefaultValues(id)} });
                          jQuery('#list').editRow(id,true); 
                          lastsel2=id;
                         }

```
                 },
```

used on selectrow to save the row first and then change the editoption.